# How can i remove white streaks from an image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i have this image in photoshop below, and i am trying to figure out a way to get rid of all of the white parts of this image and replace with the same blue color that is there.

I have tried:

- Hue / Saturation
- Replace Color Tool

and neither seems to give me what I want.

Is there anyway to do a replace of the white streaks in this image and replace with the blue color?

[image]

Comment: do you want to keep the greys? e.g. so it is a gradient from grey to transparant?

Comment: Selective Color might be useful. Though, if you take the whites out of the image, it'll look very flat...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're going for correctly, the most expedient way would be to apply a gradient map from dark blue to light blue. I got this result with about 60 seconds of trial and error:

[image: gradient map]

The process is basically:

- Create a gradient map adjustment layer
- Sample the image for the blue values you want to use
- Use them as color stops, moving the stops until the levels are about where you want them. Add as many stops as you need to achieve a wider color range with more depth. Wiggle them around until it feels right.

For reference, [here is the gradient map i used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhGke.png)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The [Eliminate White](http://www.edesign.com/filters/) filter will replace white with transparency.  You may need to apply Layer > Matting > Remove White Matte after this to get the colors right.  Then, you can paint or fill in what you want on a new layer behind this one.